# How to remove border of material.textfield.TextInputEditText (Material EditText)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, material-design

can't remove the bottom border of Material Edit Text.

here is the code I've tried:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/register_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Output is:[image: Edit Text]

Comment: That's not a border it's the input line, I don't think you can delete but you can change it's color to blend with the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to remove the bottom line.
thanks all

```
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:hint=" "
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    >

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/usernameEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:hint="Username"
                        android:background="#00000000"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```